# How to grant file MOVE permission on NTFS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ntfs

I wonder what is needed in terms of the NTFS Security permission to grant user to do file READ+WRITE+MOVE from one directory to another but NO DELETE ?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think its possible. A move effectively **is** a delete in the source location, followed by a create in the new location.

Comment: @DJPon3 nearly correct, although the order is reversed - a file is relinked / copied at the destination first and deleted at the source afterwards

Comment: You're right of course @syneticon-dj - I was just making the point informally that a move contains a delete operation by design, I appreciate I wasn't being precise.

Comment: @DJPon3 -- Why not post this as an answer?  I was about to post exactly that response...

Comment: Good point, @KyleSmith, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think its possible to do this because MOVE isn't a permission in itself. A move operation on an NTFS object involves creating a link in the target directory location and then deleting the link from the source directory location - the delete permission is therefore an inherent part of moving an object.

Comment: It seems that you are right man, I cannot configure it in anyway even with the advanced permission settings.